# How to fix 'Access denied - error 403' in a SharePoint-based flow

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I'm trying to use the Sharepoint -> Get File Content action in Power Automate, but I'm getting a 403 error - Access Denied. I am using the same login for SPO and Power Automate. I have (for now) hard-coded a file to fetch - I can definitely browse to it, but for some reason I get the error in Power Automate. Is there another permission that I need to be granted to access the same file via Power Automate that I might be missing?

I have tried Get File Content with several different files, and they all give the same result. In each case, I can manually browse to the site/library/folder where the file is and download it, using the same login.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made some changes on the sharepoint permissions?

Have you recreate a new connection to sharepoint in flow connections?

In many cases, an error code of 403 appears in a flow fail because of an authentication error. If you have this type of error, you can usually fix an authentication error by updating the connection,please make sure you have update the connection.

You could refer to link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/fix-flow-failures

If you have updated the connection and the issue still exists,I afraid that there is some permissions setted in the sharepoint forbid you to access the sharepoint.

Please take a try to contact with the sharepoint administrator to see if you have been access denied in sharepoint.